# MongoDB: .exec() promise: Have to use .doc to get the document from Object.assign()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Book schema that looks like this:

```
{
  title: String,
  name: {
    enVersion: String,
    frVersion: String
  }
}
```

I am returning a list of books with this, I replace the name field by the value of the version, which is store in the version variable.

```
Book
  .find(query)
  .exec()
  .then(books => _.map(books, b => Object.assign({}, b, { name: b.name[version])))
  .then(books => reply(books))
  .catch(err => reply(err))
```

The problem is that, the Object that `Object.assign()` is returning seems to come from another planet. To get it to work, I have to replace that line with this:

```
.then(books => _.map(books, b => Object.assign({}, b._doc, { name: b._doc.name[version])))
```

I know it should be done differently, please help.

Comment: Are you using something like `mongoose`?

Comment: Yes, Book is a mongoose Model

Comment: Use [`.toObject`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909509/mongoose-toobject-virtuals-true)

Comment: toObject did it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `mongoose` and you're wanting to work with plain objects, you'll probably want to change your code to look something like:

```
Book
  .find(query)
  .exec()
  .then(books => _.map(books, b => b.toObject()) // The important line
  .then(books => _.map(books, b => Object.assign({}, b, { name: b.name[version])))
  .then(books => reply(books))
  .catch(err => reply(err))
```

The call to `toObject` converts your Book document to a plain JavaScript object without any of the Mongoose specific logic.

Comment: Good, I prefer this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could do with a built-in `toObject()` or `toJSON()` mongoose methods

```
  .then(books => _.map(books, b => { ...b.toObject(), { name: b.name[version] }))
```

Also you could set up a `virtual` on a model which will return current name depending on locale or a `method` depending on the situation. Mongoose schema options (second param) allows to control which virtuals are included into the result of toObject() and toJSON()

```
BookSchema.virtual('localname').get(function() {
  return this.name[CURRENT_LOCALE];
});

BookSchema.method('getLocalname', function(locale) {
  return this.name[locale];
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.