# mongodb _id with graphql and document.toObject()

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, graphql-js

Let's use a basic mongodb query that returns one item:

```
const result = await db.myCollection.findById('xxxx')
return result;
```

This query result given to graphql works fine.

But now, if I return a `result.toObject()`, it's not working anymore.

I got this following error:

```
"message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field MyCollection.id."
```

Why with `toObject()`, the mapping between `_id` and `id` can't be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The id generated by MongoDB will be a `_id` field -- it's mongoose that's [actually mapping it for you](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id).

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default
>   which returns the documents _id field cast to a string, or in the case
>   of ObjectIds, its hexString. If you don't want an id getter added to
>   your schema, you may disable it passing this option at schema
>   construction time.

They key here is that the `id` field is a **virtual getter**. In order to include those in the generated object, you have to pass the appropriate option to `toObject`:

```
result.toObject({ virtuals: true })
```

See the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26909782/6024220) for more details.